# Call property by string

Tags: php

I need help in a specific situation...

I wanna access a property of object by a string in a loop... and that property is actually an object with it's own properties ofcourse.

More specifically, `$object->$object->property;`

Some code that **doesn't work**:

```
$objectAtribute = 'property->propertyOfObject';
echo $object->$objectAtribute;
```

How can it be done !?

Btw I am getting an error :undefined property

Tnx

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: @Eric the approach can actually be quite practical when parsing JSON configuration files with many optional attributes, with a 'model' describing what properties are there.

Comment: @Niels In that case I'd simply express the paths into the object using a notation like `foo.bar.baz`, `explode` that and recurse into the JSON object with a simple loop. Takes two or three lines of code and is much cleaner.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you're trying access a **single** property that's actually called `property->propertyOfObject`. Try breaking it up:

```
$className = 'className';
$object = new $className();

$propertyName = 'propertyName';
echo $object->$propertyName;
```

Or if you don't want to create a new variable:

```
echo $object->{'propertyName'};
```

If your object's class implements [ArrayAccess](http://php.net/manual/en/class.arrayaccess.php), then you can simply use

```
echo $object['propertyName'];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$objectProperty       = 'property';
$objectObjectProperty = 'propertyOfObject';

echo $object->$objectProperty->$objectObjectProperty;
```

`'property->propertyOfObject'` won't work without ugly `eval` tricks or manual "parsing", don't even get yourself down the road where you are even thinking about doing that. Then your code is too "dynamic" and punching the monkey too much.